# Where are the Content Delivery services after installing Tridion 2011 SP1?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

We are upgrading from Tridion 5.3 SP1 to Tridion 2011 SP1. We are doing installion on fresh machines.

Installation of Content Management server went smooth.  But it seems that installation of Ccontent delivery (.NET) did not go well. "startCDinstaller.bat" executed successfully but we can't find any Tridion related service in services section (in 5.3 we had Tridion content broker, tridion content deployer etc).

Even I am not able to determine which part of installation should act as a "Web application" and which should act as a "Web service". Can anyone help me understandig correct process of installation.

Note: We are NOT using any advance topic like Audience Manager, Transation Manager, Outbound Email etc.

Comment: The ***Windows Broker Service*** is nowadays not needed anymore for .NET web web sites. The only services that you might still want are the Deployer Service and the Cache Channel Service, which you have to select in the installer.

Comment: Hi Frank,  We are using .NET not Java.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many of the Windows Services that used to be installed on Tridion Content Delivery servers before Tridion 2009 used to be simply wrapper services to keep the underlying JVM alive between calls. They were only needed for ASP and ASP.NET web sites. Java-based web sites would host the Content Delivery jars inside the JVM of their own application server, so they didn't need those services.

Since Tridion 2009 a JVM is instantiated inside every application pool that hosts a ASP.NET web site that uses Tridion Content Delivery functionality. Since this means the JVM is now hosted inside your .NET process, the Windows Services for this functionality are not needed anymore.

Windows services that you typically won't need anymore on Tridion 2009 and up (unless you are using classic ASP):

- Content Delivery Broker
- Content Delivery Linking

You may/probably will still need the following Windows Services:

- Content Delivery Cache Channel
- Content Delivery Deployer (unless you use HTTP transport with InProcessDeploy set to false)

I simply don't remember which other services there used to be. If you find yourself wondering what happened to one of the services, mention it in a comment (or update the question) and I will add it to the correct list.

Comment: As per your previous suggestion I run the installter again and selected Content Delivery Cache Channel and Content Delivery Deployer now I can see these windows services. During installation I changed the path to D:\ but still I can see Tridion folder is created on C:\ with subfolders incoming and log, Can I change/move them to D:\ ?

Comment: Those folders are created because you have configuration files pointing to them. If you move the folders without modifying the configuration files, they will just be recreated next time the process wants to write something in them. Just look at the ..._conf.xml files of all your Content Delivery modules (deployer, web app, etc) and find/modify the paths in there.

Comment: Thanks Frank, I will check those files and modify.  If I have any more doubts I will get back to you.

Comment: Thanks for the edits Q. I completely forgot about the Linking service.

Comment: Do we also need to install Tridion Monitoring Agent Windows service?

Comment: That depends on whether you want to use the system monitoring functionality that has been included in Tridion since it's 5.3 version. All Tridion functionality is documented extensively and I suggest looking up what the Monitoring Agent does in that documentation and determining whether you want it from that.